# how to update an element in a es6 array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I've an array of objects and I want to modify a property in the object.

I know we can remove the object using splice function.Is the only option to remove and add it back?

Comment: no, you can directly change it ... `array[index].property = value` ... or, as the question implies, to replace an object ... `array[index] = newobject`

Answer (score 4):

You have to modify it directly (assuming You know index)

```
YourArray[index].ObjectProperty = YourValue
```

It does not make any difference if it's ES6 or not

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is modify a prop in the object, theres no need to remove it from the array.

```
arr[2].prop = newValue;
```